# How to remove a node from a dict using jsonpath-ng?

Tags: python, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

In Python I have a list of dictionaries and I want to remove a given node from each dictionary in the list. I don't know anything about those dictionaries except they all have the same (unknown) schema. The node to be removed may be anywhere in the dictionaries and it is specified by a [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression.

Example:

Input data:

```json
[
  { "top": { "lower": 1, "other": 1 } },
  { "top": { "lower": 2, "other": 4 } },
  { "top": { "lower": 3, "other": 9 } }
]
```

Node to be removed: `$.*.top.lower`

Expected result:

```json
[
  { "top": { "other": 1 } },
  { "top": { "other": 4 } },
  { "top": { "other": 9 } }
]
```

Using the [`jsonpath`](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-python/) library my first attempt was this:

```py
from jsonpath import JSONPath

def remove_node_from_dict(data, node):
    node_key = JSONPath(node).segments.pop()
    for record in data:
        del record[node_key]
```

but this works only if the node to remove is at the top level of the dictionaries.
Researching for solutions I came across the [`jsonpath-ng`](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/) library which claims to have "the ability to update or remove nodes in the tree". However, I couldn't find any documentation on this - how is it done?

EDIT:

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27178852/11474852) answer to a related question I found a solution that works at least for simple paths (no filters etc.) using plain Python (not the `jsonpath-ng` library). Which would be sufficient for my use case. I would still like to learn how to do it with `jsonpath-ng` in a more generic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **jsonpath-ng** library, in fact, allows to do nodes removal using the `.filter()` method.
They've added examples to the documentation only recently, thanks to reported issue [#44](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/issues/44).

I had to change your JSONPath expression to `$.[*].top.lower`:

```
from jsonpath_ng import parse


test_data = [
    { "top": { "lower": 1, "other": 1 } },
    { "top": { "lower": 2, "other": 4 } },
    { "top": { "lower": 3, "other": 9 } }
]

jsonpath_expr = parse("$.[*].top.lower")
jsonpath_expr.filter(lambda d: True, test_data)
print(test_data)
```

And I've got the next output:

```
[{'top': {'other': 1}}, {'top': {'other': 4}}, {'top': {'other': 9}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive solution which I've used in the past:

```py
import copy
import jsonpath_ng.ext as jp

def remove_matched_element(path, spec):
    _new_spec = copy.deepcopy(spec)
    jep = jp.parse(path)
    for match in jep.find(spec):
        _t_path = "$"
        spec_path = _new_spec
        spec_path_parent = None
        for pe in str(match.full_path).split("."):
            if _t_path != "$" and type(jp.parse(_t_path).find(_new_spec)[0].value) == list:
                _t_path = f"{_t_path}{'.'}{pe}"
                _idx = int(pe.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
                spec_path_parent = spec_path
                spec_path = spec_path[_idx]
            elif _t_path != "$" and type(jp.parse(_t_path).find(_new_spec)[0].value) == dict and pe == "[0]":
                keyp = list(jp.parse(_t_path).find(_new_spec)[0].value.keys())[0]
                _idx = keyp
                _t_path = f"{_t_path}.{keyp}"
                spec_path_parent = spec_path
                spec_path = spec_path[keyp]
            else:
                if type(spec_path) == list:
                    _idx = int(pe.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
                    _t_path = f"{_t_path}[{_idx}]"
                else:
                    _idx = pe
                    _t_path = f"{_t_path}{'.'}{pe}"
                spec_path_parent = spec_path
                spec_path = spec_path[_idx]
        spec_path_parent.pop(_idx)
    return _new_spec


def test_soc_sol():
    spec = [
        {"top": {"lower": 1, "other": 1}},
        {"top": {"lower": 2, "other": 4}},
        {"top": {"lower": 3, "other": 9}}
    ]

    print(
        yaml.safe_dump(remove_matched_element("$..lower", spec)))
```

The above code results in:

```json
[
    {
        "top": {
            "other": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "top": {
            "other": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "top": {
            "other": 9
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What's `jp`? Can't be `import jsonpath as jp`...

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to include the imports now. Jp is the python library [jsonpath-ng](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng)

Answer (score -2):

If you know the schema is fixed, you can simply remove the key like this

```
l = [
  { "top": { "lower": 1, "other": 1 } },
  { "top": { "lower": 2, "other": 4 } },
  { "top": { "lower": 3, "other": 9 } }
]

for d in l:
    del d["top"]["lower"]
```

Comment: The schema is fixed within the list but unkown when the `remove_node_from_dict()` function is called. Also the node to be removed is only given at runtime. Hence, the code needs to be generic.